# Netbans MySQL LIKE statement

Tags: java, mysql

I have a search box in my application. The function to search and return the result works, but the way it's done is not efficient, it only displays what you're searching for when you've written out the whole string.
To get rid of this inefficiency i decided to use the `like` SQL statement. I managed to make it work, but another downside to how i used it is that in the search box you have to insert the percent signs yourself, so it would look something like this `%<search-string>%`. This is not only ugly to look at, but it's also not user friendly.

What do i need to change in my code to make it so that i can use the `like` statement without having to put `%` in the search box?

Here is the code:

```
 try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/GateControl", "admin", "adminpassword");
            String selection = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            PreparedStatement insert = con1.prepareStatement("select * from Visitors where "+selection+" like?");
            insert.setString(1, (String) jTextField1.getText());
            ResultSet rs = insert.executeQuery();
            
            
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
 
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
```

*Ignore the indentation, it got messed up when i placed it here, its alright on Netbeans*

Comment: tried something like %?% Also, how do you think this is netbeans related? just so you know: swallowing exceptions is asking for problems further on, at least log them

Comment: i tried %?% it doesn't work. its Netbeans related because i used netbeans...
logging wont help..no error is show, the porgram just doesnt work..but yeah, ```%?%``` doesnt work

Comment: You used numbers. Doesn't make it a math issue. This is not netbeans related, even though you use it. How about "... where " + selection + " like %" + ((String)jTextField.getText()) + "%"

Comment: your solution works on intellij but not netbeans..do you now see why i made it clear that i'm using netbeans?

Comment: No, I just understand why you keep thinking this is a netbeans issue